# PyTorch moving average computation creates inplace operation

Tags: pytorch

I have a loss function that depends on an "exponential moving average" `Z`. A minimal example (pay special attention to the `getUpdatedZ` function):

```py
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

class FeedForward(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(FeedForward, self).__init__()
      
        self.model = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(1, 100),
                                   nn.ReLU(),
                                   nn.Linear(100, 1))
    
    def forward(self, x):
        return self.model(x)

model = FeedForward()
nEpochs = 100

optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(params=model.parameters(), lr=1e-3)

def getTrainingPoints():
  return torch.rand(1000, 1)

def lossFunction(X, Z):
  # Returning Z here is enough to expose the problem. The real loss is more complicated.
  return Z

def getUpdatedZ(X, Z):
  U = model(X)
  Znew = torch.mean(U)
  # Having Z in this computation creates an inplace operation (I'm not sure why).
  # Returning, for example, Znew, does not cause any issues (but the computation is incorrect)
  return 0.2 * Z + 0.8 * Znew 

Z = torch.tensor([1.0])
X = getTrainingPoints()
for i in range(nEpochs):
  optimizer.zero_grad()
  Z = getUpdatedZ(X, Z)
  loss = lossFunction(X, Z)
  # loss function depends on gradient of the model in the real version of the code, hence retain_graph=True
  loss.backward(retain_graph=True) 
  optimizer.step()
```

I get the following error:

```
RuntimeError: one of the variables needed for gradient computation has been modified by an inplace operation: [torch.FloatTensor [100, 1]], which is output 0 of AsStridedBackward0, is at version 2; expected version 1 instead. Hint: enable anomaly detection to find the operation that failed to compute its gradient, with torch.autograd.set_detect_anomaly(True).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some trials, I think that the error arises because you are computing a recursive function (`Z = getUpdatedZ(X, Z)`) but you are changing some of its parameters (the weights of the `Linear` modules) at each iteration through `optimizer.step()`.

You can `backward()` just at the end of the for cycle, or you may want to break the autodifferentiation graph, for example by calling `Z.detach()` after `loss.backward()`. Sometimes this trick is used to avoid too complex and inefficient backpropagations (check, for example [this](https://www.gabormelli.com/RKB/Truncated_Back-Propagation_Through_Time_(TBPTT)_Algorithm)).

However in both cases, this will change the structure of the optimized function, so be sure of what you are doing.

Comment: Thank you, I think recursion is indeed the problem here. As you say, there will be implications on the graph by calling detach, and I can see why not detaching could lead to some pretty major performance implications. Back to the drawing board!